# What is the bootstrap process of an Angular Application? When app.component.htm loads and display?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am new to Angular. I am working on a web application using Angular. When I start the project `app.component.(ts, html...) and app.module.ts` generated.

> I am wondering when will the `app.component.html` will be rendered?
>
> What should I put in `app.component.html`,
>
> And when should I create an another `component, like homepage component`?

Will there be any differences between putting `homepage` in `app.component.html` and putting homepage in another `component.html`?

Comment: i think you you are asking about how to structure your project like component placement and router and sub route placement , what i can do is provide you with one my sample code  :https://github.com/JOELJOSEPHCHALAKUDY/angular-github-user-info-demo/tree/master/src

Comment: also note that there is always a root module which has a bootstartap component or the root component into which other modules of components are loaded  into . normally  we use `app.component.ts`  but  you can change the same  though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Welcome to Angular

So how bootstrap process works in `Angular Application`.

1. The entry point to every Angular Application is the `main.ts` file which contains this last line.

[image]

The `platformBrowserDynamic()` part of this line of code indicates that we are about to boot Angular in a browser environment.
The `bootstrapModule()` function bootstrap our root module which is `app.module.ts`.

2. `AppModule(app.module.ts)` is an entry module and also root module for our application.
3. `app.component.ts` is an entry component that we specify in `app.module.ts`.

[image]

> **So what should you keep in `app.component.ts`**

You can consider app.component.ts as a `HomeComponent` also, but it is good to keep `HomeComponent` seprately and giving it's reference to app.component.ts.

You should create separate component for each separate page in your application.

*Image source: medium.com*

Answer (score 1):

app.component.html is root component file. so its content display top. you create another component its will be render with root component. you can implement app routing module and define here application list of url for file. other word app.component.html is master page. and create new component is child page.

```
 <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Content >> -->
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <!-- Content << -->
    /<body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

app.component.html is the page that will be rendered from your application. All the component's html pages created will be rendered with in app.component.html.

component's html pages will be rendered based on the routes set in app.module.ts.

for eg: if the route for 'home' is set as homeComponent then home.component.html will be rendered inside app.component.html.

To serve this purpose of dynamically loading the required components the app.component.html will have its content as nothing but output of routing module as,

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

reading further through the angular guide will help in understanding these concepts in depth. https://angular.io/